# Add JS src in another file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many `.js` files loaded in my `index.html` in the following format:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Is there an option to create an HTML file where I will source all my JS and CSS files and then include this HTML file in my `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to load a HTML file, add a link tag with an import in the rel attribute and an href that contains a path to the HTML file. For example, if you want to load a HTML file called myImports.html into index.html:

index.html

```
<link rel="import" href="myImports.html" >
```

You can load any resource including scripts, stylesheets, and web fonts, into the imported HTML just like you do to regular HTML files:

myImports.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Whereas doctype, html, head, body aren't required. HTML Imports will immediately load the imported document, resolve subresources and execute JavaScript, if any.

Comment: This is an experimental solution! Chrome supports this in version 31, and Firefox will not ship support for this. http://caniuse.com/#search=import

Comment: Than take a look at this accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/3161980

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making on html file that include all js and css files. the more practical Solution is to merge all your javascript/CSS files into one file. then include that file into your html. Their are tools available that can help you to achieve this automatically e.g Gulp, YEOMAN etc.